# How to execute this sorting process in pyspark?

Tags: sorting, pyspark

I have tried map, mapValues and sort, but nothing works.
The question is described as follows:
"by the similarity (the second one in the value), if same, choose the user that has smallest ID (the first one in the value)." 
And the list of Key-Value pair is :

```
[
    (18, [(2, 0.5)]),
    (30, [(19, 0.5), (6, 0.25)]),
    (6, [(30, 0.25), (20, 0.2), (19, 0.2)]),
    (19, [(30, 0.5), (8, 0.2), (6, 0.2)]),
    (2, [(18, 0.5)]),
    (26, [(9, 0.2)]),
    (9, [(26, 0.2)])
]
```

I want to get:

```
[
    (18, [(2, 0.5)]),
    (30, [(19, 0.5), (6, 0.25)]),
    (6, [(30, 0.25), (19, 0.2)]),
    (19, [(30, 0.5), (6, 0.2)]),
    (2, [(18, 0.5)]),
    (26, [(9, 0.2)]),
    (9, [(26, 0.2)])
]
```

Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much straight forward. Just need to figure out the necessary transformations:

```
data = [(18, [(2, 0.5)]),
 (30, [(19, 0.5), (6, 0.25)]),
 (6, [(30, 0.25), (20, 0.2), (19, 0.2)]),
 (19, [(30, 0.5), (8, 0.2), (6, 0.2)]),
 (2, [(18, 0.5)]),
 (26, [(9, 0.2)]),
 (9, [(26, 0.2)])]

rdd1 = sc.parallelize(data)

rdd2 = rdd1.flatMapValues(lambda x:x)

rdd3 = rdd2.map(lambda x: ((x[0], x[1][1]),x[1][0]))

rdd4 = rdd3.reduceByKey(min)

rdd5 = rdd4.map(lambda x: (x[0][0], (x[1], x[0][1])))

rdd6 = rdd5.reduceByKey(lambda x,y: [x,y])
rdd6.collect()
[(9, (26, 0.2)),
 (26, (9, 0.2)),
 (18, (2, 0.5)),
 (30, [(6, 0.25), (19, 0.5)]),
 (2, (18, 0.5)),
 (6, [(30, 0.25), (19, 0.2)]),
 (19, [(30, 0.5), (6, 0.2)])]
```